# Android studio - Change string in textView

Tags: java, android

I have some stings in the `styles/string.xml` as below:

```
<string name="string1">something</string>
<string name="string2">some other thisn</string>
<string name="string3">asdfgh jkl</string>
<string name="string4">qwerty uiop</string>
.
.
.
```

and I have a textView and a button in my current activity. When I click the button, the text in the textView has to change (to the next sting) according to what is currently shown. That is, if the current text in textView is `string1`, then it should change to `string2`.

The code below doesn't work but will illustrate what I am looking for

```
count = 0;
public void onClick(View v) {
                count++;
                str="R.string.string" + count;
                textView.setText(str);
            }
```

I have to somehow convert the string to the actual value of (say)`R.string.string1`.
Is there a way to do that? Or is there any other method to achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: You can bring your resource ids into an array and use counter to index them.  You need to call a `getString` either from context or `Resources.getSystem()` with those ids to get the string you want.  `count` can be made into a class field so that it persists between clicks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a string array resource similar to this one below:

```xml
<resources>
    <string-array name="my_string_array">
        <item>stringa</item>
        <item>stringb</item>
        <item>another string</item>
        <item>yet another string</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

```java
  // you can use a string array resource
  String[] strings = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.my_string_array)
  int count = 0;
  void onClick(View v) {
    if (count < strings.length)
       textView.setText(strings[count])
       count++;
  }
```

Comment: @possum, I updated the answer to include a sample xml string array resource

Comment: Seems like I can't access the string array with (R.string.my_string_array). It only shows the strings, It's not showing string arrays.    (edited) I have figured it out, It should be (R.array.my_string_array). Thanks for the answer Micah.